# Punctuation for a compound question

Tags: punctuation, questions

What is the proper punctuation for the following?

Have you heard, I like chocolate ice cream (?) (.)

Should it be two separate sentences?   Have you heard?  I like chocolate ice cream.

Is there a way to create a compound sentence?

Comment: Personally I would use a colon: "Have you heard: I like chocolate ice cream?"

Answer (score 1):

*Have you heard? I like chocolate ice cream.*

or

*Have you heard that I like chocolate ice cream?*

Comment: Eh, those are good to rephrase OP's example... but there are still cases where you can't do that and I think the question stands.  Give me a second to come up with some.

Comment: ... When there's a real emphasis on the first clause: 'Have you heard!?  He's only gone and bought Buckingham Palace!' The alternative with the that-clause loses emphasis.